# @ManyToOne to entity in @MappedSuperclass overrides fetch strategy of @ManyToOne to same entity in subclass

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have recently added JPA Auditing to our Entity objects.  Here is the abstract class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties( { "createdBy", "lastModifiedBy", "createdDate", "lastModifiedDate" } )
public abstract class AbstractEntity<PK extends Serializable> implements Auditable<User, PK> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    private PK id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private User createdBy;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private User lastModifiedBy;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    //Getters and Setters from here
```

I have set the relationships to the `User` entity to Lazy to avoid extra queries as those properties are rarely used in our application code.

Here is my `@Entity` class that is giving me trouble:

```
@Entity
//So the outcomes property can be Lazy fetched in a Repository using an @EntityGraph
@NamedEntityGraph( name = "Participant.lazy" )
public class Participant extends AbstractEntity<Long> implements Serializable,     Identifiable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" )
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "event_id" )
    private Event event;

    @Column( nullable = false )
    private boolean virtual;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "participant" )
    @OrderBy( "id DESC" )
    private Set<ParticipantOutcome> outcomes;

    //Constructors, Getters, Setters, Equal and Hashcode from here
```

If I remove the Auditable properties in AbstractEntity then the `Participant.user` will be fetched Eagerly.  However, if I leave in the Auditable properties `Participant.user` is forced to a Lazy Fetch.

Is it possible to have different fetch strategies in muliple `@ManyToOne` relationships to the same `@Entity` or do I have to remove the Lazy hint on `AbstractEntity.createdBy` and `AbstractEntity.lastModifiedBy`?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing it requires switching to property-type access for the properties you'd like to override:

So the AbstractEntity must be changed like this:

```
private User createdBy;

private User lastModifiedBy;

private Date lastModifiedDate;

@Access(AccessType.property) 
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
public User getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

@Access(AccessType.property) 
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
public User getLastModifiedBy() {
    return lastModifiedBy;
}
```

And the Participant will override these methods:

```
@Access(AccessType.property) 
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public User getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

@Access(AccessType.property) 
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public User getLastModifiedBy() {
    return lastModifiedBy;
}
```